# Substring sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

I want to display after 8 characters, how to do that through `substring`.
For contact name is `amjad habib`, I want to display `amjad hab...`.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(contractname, 1, 8)
from contracts
where contractid = 613
```

Comment: `substring(contractname, 9, len(contractname))`

Comment: how to display dots after 8 characters?

Answer (score 4):

This will cut your strings to a max length you can specify. The dots are only appended in case the string is to long and therefore truncated. Shorter strings are shown "as is":

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(TheName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('short'),('exactly8'),('something longer');

DECLARE @MaxLength INT=8;

SELECT TheName 
      ,LEFT(TheName,@MaxLength) + CASE WHEN LEN(TheName)>@MaxLength THEN '...' ELSE '' END AS CutToMaxLength 

FROM @tbl
```

The result

```
TheName               CutToMaxLength
short                 short
exactly8              exactly8
something longer      somethin...
```

Comment: Pet peeve: when the truncated string + dots is longer than the string untrunc'ed. I would use 2 variables instead of `@MaxLength`, i.e. `@CutOffAt = 11` and `@CutOffTo = 8`

Comment: @steenbergh, If you need a dedicated max length **including the dots**, I'd define a variable `@truncSign` with `...` in it and then use it's `LEN(@truncSign)` in the calculation... But this is rather sophisticated ;-)